# SQL Server 2016 Sub Query Guidance

Tags: sql, subquery, sql-server-2016

I am currently working on an assignment for my SQL class and I am stuck. I'm not looking for full code to answer the question, just a little nudge in the right direction. If you do provide full code would you mind a small explanation as to why you did it that way (so I can actually learn something.)

Here is the question:

> Write a SELECT statement that returns three columns: `EmailAddress`, `ShipmentId`, and the order total for each Client. To do this, you can group the result set by the `EmailAddress` and `ShipmentId` columns. In addition, you must calculate the order total from the columns in the `ShipItems` table.
>
> Write a second SELECT statement that uses the first SELECT statement in its FROM clause. The main query should return two columns: the Client’s email address and the largest order for that Client. To do this, you can group the result set by the `EmailAddress` column.

I am confused on how to pull in the `EmailAddress` column from the `Clients` table, as in order to join it I have to bring in other tables that aren't being used. I am assuming there is an easier way to do this using sub Queries as that is what we are working on at the time.

Comment: Note there is a difference between a "subquery" and a "correlated subquery" - I know this can put-off some beginners who think that all subqueries are correlated subqueries. Not that this applies to your question, btw.

Comment: Please provided the definitions of the tables you're using. So far I can see `Clients  ( EmailAddress )`, `Shipments ( ShipmentId )` and `ShipItems ( ShipmentId )`  - is it just those 3 tables and columns? Where is the order-total defined? Is it stored in `Shipments` or must it be computed from `ShipItems`?

Comment: You wrote "`EmailAddress` [...] as in order to join it I have to bring in other tables that aren't being used." - you haven't said what other tables are involved or why you think they "aren't being used". As far as I can see, they *are* being used.

Answer (score 1):

Think of SQL as working with sets of data as opposed to just tables. Tables are merely a set of data. So when you view data this way you immediately see that the query below returns a set of data consisting of the entirety of another set, being a table:

```
SELECT * FROM MyTable1
```

Now, if you were to only get the first two columns from MyTable1 you would return a different set that consisted only of columns 1 and 2:

```
SELECT col1, col2 FROM MyTable1
```

Now you can treat this second set, a subset of data as a "table" as well and query it like this:

```
SELECT 
    *
FROM (
    SELECT
        col1,
        col2
    FROM
        MyTable1
)
```

This will return all the columns from the two columns provided in the inner set.

So, your inner query, which I won't write for you since you appear to be a student, and that wouldn't be right for me to give you the entire answer, would be a query consisting of a GROUP BY clause and a SUM of the order value field. But the key thing you need to understand is this set thinking: you can just wrap the ENTIRE query inside brackets and treat it as a table the way I have done above. Hopefully this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You need a subquery, like this:

```
select emailaddress, max(OrderTotal) as MaxOrder 
from
( -- Open the subquery
select Cl.emailaddress, 
       Sh.ShipmentID, 
       sum(SI.Value) as OrderTotal -- Use the line item value column in here
from Client Cl -- First table
inner join Shipments Sh -- Join the shipments
  on Sh.ClientID =  Cl.ClientID
inner join ShipItem SI -- Now the items
  on SI.ShipmentID = Sh.ShipmentID
group by C1.emailaddress, Sh.ShipmentID -- here's your grouping for the sum() aggregation
) -- Close subquery
group by emailaddress -- group for the max()
```

Answer (score 0):

For the first query you can join the Clients to Shipments (on ClientId).
And Shipments to the ShipItems table (on ShipmentId).
Then group the results, and count or sum the total you need.

Using aliases for the tables is usefull, certainly when you select fields from the joined tables that have the same column name.

```
select 
 c.EmailAddress, 
 i.ShipmentId,
 SUM((i.ShipItemPrice - i.ShipItemDiscountAmount) * i.Quantity) as TotalPriceDiscounted
from ShipItems i
join Shipments s on (s.ShipmentId = i.ShipmentId)
left join Clients c on (c.ClientId = s.ClientId)
group by i.ShipmentId, c.EmailAddress
order by i.ShipmentId, c.EmailAddress;
```

Using that grouped query in a subquery, you can get the Maximum total per EmailAddress.

```
select EmailAddress, 
-- max(TotalShipItems) as MaxTotalShipItems,
max(TotalPriceDiscounted) as MaxTotalPriceDiscounted
from (
   select 
    c.EmailAddress, 
    -- i.ShipmentId, 
    -- count(*) as TotalShipItems,
    SUM((i.ShipItemPrice - i.ShipItemDiscountAmount) * i.Quantity) as TotalPriceDiscounted
   from ShipItems i
   join Shipments s on (s.ShipmentId = i.ShipmentId)
   left join Clients c on (c.ClientId = s.ClientId)
   group by i.ShipmentId, c.EmailAddress
) q
group by EmailAddress
order by EmailAddress
```

Note that an ORDER BY is mostly meaningless inside a subquery if you don't use TOP.

Comment: Okay, so I guess I should have put a touch more info. The ShipItems table does not share a PK or FK with the Clients table. The only table that shares any PK or FKs with the flients table is the Shipments table. This is why originally I didn't see how you would do this without bringing in the Shipments table. But the only thing you are using it for is to be able to join the Clients and ShipItems table.

Comment: Re reading your post again, I think I have it figured out. Thanks, Will post again if any extra help is needed.

Comment: @BrettHawkins  I changed the second query so it now includes a Shipments table.  I figured such table was overlooked in the original question.

Comment: Okay, so while writing the first query, I have it all done but it does not give any results. 
Here is the Query I have written:

SELECT c.EmailAddress, s.ShipmentId, SUM((sh.ShipItemPrice - sh.ShipItemDiscountAmount) * sh.Quantity) AS OrderTotal
FROM Clients AS c JOIN Shipments AS s
ON c.ClientID = s.ClientID
JOIN ShipItems AS sh
ON s.ShipmentID = sh.ShipItemsID
GROUP BY EmailAddress, s.ShipmentID

Comment: @BrettHawkins I think you should use the ShipItems as a base table, and join the others on it.  And with a LEFT join to the clients table. That way you'll also get a count for when the ClientId can't be linked.

Comment: Thank you, I had a type on one of my joins using the ShipItemID and not ShipmentID, and that is why I was not getting any results. The query is working as intended now. Thank you again.

Comment: One last question for you, What is the purpose of the 'q' At the end of the sub query? What exactly is it doing? I have figured out that is makes the query work, but why is this so?

Comment: @BrettHawkins That's because in MS SQL it's required that a subquery also gets an alias. Well, at least if that subquery isn't used for an [IN](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_in.asp) or an [EXISTS](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_exists.asp).

Comment: If you don't like the short alias name 'q' (short for Query) then you could choose a more specific alias name like f.e. `MyLovelySubquery`